# remove border around bxslider slides

Tags: jquery, css, bxslider

I am using jquery bx slider. I want to remove the border around the slides. 
How do I do this?
I tried this, but it didn't work:

```css
ul.bxslider {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0;
  box-shadow: 0;
  border: none;
}
```

Any other ways to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As accepted answer is no more correct (in 2018 - bxSlider v4.2.12), I added here working CSS:

```
.bx-wrapper {
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 0;
}
```

`!important` is not necessary, if you add this CSS after linking to bxSlider's CSS file.

Answer (score 2):

the "box-shadow" is not set to the ul but to the parent (".bx-wrapper .bx-viewport"), remove the "box-shadow". you also have 5px width of border but the color is white (#fff) so choose whatever you need it or not.

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport
{
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Not working in 2018, bxSlider v4.2.12, added solution worked in 2018.

Answer (score 2):

```
.bx-viewport {
    position: static!important; /* center to page correctly */
    border: 0!important; /* border */
    -webkit-box-shadow: none!important; /* these two shadows */
    box-shadow: none!important;
}
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Comment: Not working in 2018, bxSlider v4.2.12, added solution worked in 2018.

Answer (score 2):

The only working solution for me was to change the wrapper class:

```
slider.bxSlider({
    wrapperClass: 'your-class-here'
});
```

From the documentation:
wrapperClass is string with default value 'bx-wrapper'.

wrapperClass - Class to wrap the slider in. Change to prevent from using default bxSlider styles.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at styles of rendered `bxSlider` you will see the wrapper `<div class="bx-wrapper" style="max-width: 1100px;">` and shadow is set by 
`bx-wrapper` class. So you can hide shadow it by override this class.

Previous solution didn't work for me. It worked when i add `!important` to styles:

```css
.bx-wrapper {
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Not working in 2018, bxSlider v4.2.12, added solution worked in 2018.